# Redirect base url magento site

Tags: html, magento, web

I want to change my base url from
    `"www.mysite.com/magento/"`
to
    `"www.mysite.com/"`
I tried to change the base url in admin panel (system - configuration - web ) and now i can't access neither to admin panel or site. What can i do?

Comment: It's probably something wrong with the .htaccess file. Do you have FTP/file access to the site main directory?

Comment: Yes i can access by FTP. What i have to do? (my files/folders are in /magento/ folder)

Comment: Look for a file called `.htaccess` inside your main site folder. Back it up, delete/rename the original one and try and see if you gain access to the admin panel. Next, in the magneto folder, create/edit .htaccess to contain: `Redirect 301 www.mysite.com/magento/ www.mysite.com/`.

Comment: More info about htaccess files is available [here](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/grid/204643080/how-do-i-redirect-my-site-using-a-htaccess-file)

Comment: I add the line to .htaccess but it doesn't work. Should i shift my files to back folder? (from site/magento to site/) ?

Comment: Or can i restore the previous situation?

Comment: I restored my situation. So now i am at the beginning, i'm trying to change the base url without reinstalling magento. Any suggestions?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49751688/magento-redirect-base-url