# Magento Redirect base url

Tags: magento, url, redirect

I have all my folders and files in `www.mysite.com/magento/` and my home page base url is `www.mysite.com/magento/`. I need to change this url to only `www.mysite.com` and if possible I don't wanna move my files from `/magento/` to the back folder.

If I use System - Configuration - Web from my magento-admin-panel, it doesn't work and I can't connect to panel.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish that using `.htaccess` and `RewriteBase`.

Here's commented out example in Magento `.htaccess` sample:

```
############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

RewriteBase /magento/
```

That should do the trick in your case.

You can read more about `RewriteBase` here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#page-header

**Edit:** In the web root, you'll need some sort of rewrite to Magento root directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !magento/
RewriteRule (.*) /magento/$1 [L]
```

Keep in mind that there are all just untested examples that should point you in the right direction. :)

Cheers.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. If I go to 'www.mysite.com' appear 'You don't have permission to access / on this server.". Probably i should put an .htaccess in the root folder. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've edited the answer with more details, couldn't add it all in the comment. :)